# android- how to filter RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a RecyclerView Adapter class , I want to filter my List , I want to filter my list base on the List class , this is my adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> list;
Context ctx;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = feedItemList;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parrent, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_parts, parrent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    FeedItem item = list.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(item.getname());
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list == null)
        return 0;
    else
        return list.size();
}



class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        name.setTypeface(typeface);


    }

}
```

}

how can I filter my data in List and update the adapter ?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean by "I want to filter my list base on the List class". Will you have lists for multiple classes? (ex: List<FeedItem>, List<FeedItemTwo>, List<FeedItemThree> etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
public int getItemViewType(int position)
```

method to get Type to each item in recycler view.
This will give you the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup) for the specified item.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Filterable in your adapter and in your activity add searchview with setOnQueryTextListener...

[this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html) link may help you to understand filterable with example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AdapterData extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterData.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    Data object;
    private ArrayList<Data> mArrayList;
    private ArrayList<Data> mFilteredList;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count,yayayan;
        public ImageView thumbnail, imgLike;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            yayayan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yayasan);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            imgLike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
        }
    }


    public AdapterData(Context mContext, ArrayList<Data> arraylist) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mArrayList = arraylist;
        mFilteredList = arraylist;

        }


    @Override
    public AdapterData.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_data, parent, false);

        return new AdapterData.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterData.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data d = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(d.getNama_data());
        holder.yayayan.setText(d.getNama_yayasan());
        holder.count.setText(d.getTtl_like() + " Like");


    }
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        if (charText.length() == 0) {//jika string kosong
            mFilteredList = mArrayList;
        } else {//filter dan buat arraybaru dengan filter query model
            ArrayList<Data> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Data wp : mArrayList) {
                if (wp.getNama_data().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    filteredList.add(wp);
                }
            }
            mFilteredList = filteredList;

        }
        //memperbarui list adapter
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }
}
```

and your actity or fragment send Arraylist data set to adapter , i hope this sample can help u ^^